# Stored procedures, binlog and SUPER privilege

Tags: mysql, amazon-rds

I tried to create this function on Amazon RDS for MySQL:

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION GetRootZoneId (zoneId INT) RETURNS INT READS SQL DATA
BEGIN
    DECLARE _id, _parentId INT;
    SELECT zoneId INTO _parentId;

    my_loop: LOOP
        SELECT id, parentId
        INTO _id,_parentId
        FROM Zone
        WHERE id = _parentId;

        IF _parentId IS NULL THEN
            LEAVE my_loop;
        END IF;
    END LOOP my_loop;

    RETURN _id;
END;
```

This would only be used in a one-off query to update an existing database table.

Running it got me the following error:

> ERROR 1419 (HY000): You do not have the SUPER privilege and
>   binary logging is enabled (you *might* want to use the less safe
>   log_bin_trust_function_creators variable)

**Does this restriction apply to stored procedures as well, or just functions?**

If it does apply to stored procedures as well, **is there any alternative to execute an equivalent code without setting `log_bin_trust_function_creators=1`?** Please note that I know how to change this setting on RDS, I'd just like to avoid that *if possible*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like **this doesn't apply to stored procedures**.

I've rewritten my code to use two procedures to do the job, instead of a statement calling a function, and that works fine.

The function above has been rewritten to be a procedure:

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE GetRootZoneId (IN zoneId INT UNSIGNED, OUT rootZoneId INT UNSIGNED)
BEGIN
    DECLARE _id, _parentId INT UNSIGNED;
    SELECT zoneId INTO _parentId;

    my_loop: LOOP
        SELECT id, parentId
        INTO _id,_parentId
        FROM Zone
        WHERE id = _parentId;

        IF _parentId IS NULL THEN
            LEAVE my_loop;
        END IF;
    END LOOP my_loop;

    SET rootZoneId = _id;
END;
```

And a second procedure calls this one to iterate on the records to update:

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE UpdateZoneCountries() BEGIN
  DECLARE done BOOLEAN DEFAULT FALSE;
  DECLARE _id INT UNSIGNED;
  DECLARE _rootId INT UNSIGNED;
  DECLARE cur CURSOR FOR SELECT id FROM Zone WHERE countryCode IS NULL;
  DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done := TRUE;

  OPEN cur;

  my_loop: LOOP
    FETCH cur INTO _id;
    IF done THEN
      LEAVE my_loop;
    END IF;
    CALL GetRootZoneId(_id, _rootId);

    UPDATE Zone SET rootId = _rootId WHERE id = _id;
  END LOOP my_loop;

  CLOSE cur;
END;
```

I successfully ran this code on RDS with the `default.mysql5.6` parameter group.

Answer (score 2):

You can't avoid it. The restriction applies also to stored procedures. The only alternative would be to have the SUPER privilege, but I don't think it's possible in this case.

Moreover, you have to declare your function as `DETERMINISTIC`, telling explicitly that you're not going to modify data:

```
CREATE FUNCTION GetRootZoneId (zoneId INT) RETURNS INT DETERMINISTIC READS SQL DATA
BEGIN
    DECLARE _id, _parentId INT;
    SELECT zoneId INTO _parentId;

    my_loop: LOOP
        SELECT id, parentId
        INTO _id,_parentId
        FROM Zone
        WHERE id = _parentId;

        IF _parentId IS NULL THEN
            LEAVE my_loop;
        END IF;
    END LOOP my_loop;

    RETURN _id;
END;
```

Comment: `DETERMINISTIC` is the only way because AmazonRDS will not relent on `SUPER` privilege. +1 !!!

Comment: Just tried with `DETERMINISTIC` and MySQL still fails with the same error on RDS, so I assume you mean I need `log_bin_trust_function_creators` + `DETERMINISTIC` then!

Comment: Also, I've rewritten my code to use stored procedures since, and it seems to work! I will detail that in an answer.